# How to use a stack to print in reverse order as opposed to the input order?

Tags: c

I want to use the program I created to turn it into a program that is output in reverse order as opposed to the input order using the stack. My code before using the stack is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>


typedef struct person {
    char name[10];
    int age;
    float salary;


}person;

int main()
{
    struct person* list[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(list) / sizeof(struct person*); i++)
    {
        list[i] = (person*)malloc(sizeof(struct person));

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("name:"); scanf_s("%s", list[i]->name, sizeof(char[10]));
        printf("age:"); scanf_s("%d", &list[i]->age);
        printf("salary:"); scanf_s("%f", &list[i]->salary);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%d name :%s, age: %dage, salary:%fsalary", i, list[i]->name, list[i]->age, list[i]->salary);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)  =>     for (int i = 2; i >-1; i--)  ?

Comment: please describe your question in more detail. Do you want to write a new program that executes this program?

Comment: You may create a new program.
You can use my program!

Answer (score 1):

Stack actually works by putting the reference of the data block or group of the data blocks to the last data that was added to it. In this case since you are using arrays as data block to store values, the reference were dependent to its index.

Adding stacks

```
|2| <- added value
|1|
```

Add 4 as new value to this stack and you'll get

```
|4|<- added value
|2|
|1|
```

And pop a value to the stack and you'll have the stack looking like this

```
|2|
|1|
```

Therefore stack is all about manipulating the latest values you added to the array/list down to the oldest value you added to the array/list. I think a good way of approaching this problem is to initialize a **head** (integer) variable that will store the index of the last element added to the array and loop from that head reference to 0.

Edit: Using your code it will actually look like this

```
int main()
{
    struct person* list[3];
    int head=-1; // meaning empty
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(list) / sizeof(struct person*); i++)
    {
        list[i] = (person*)malloc(sizeof(struct person));

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("name:"); scanf_s("%s", list[i]->name, sizeof(char[10]));
        printf("age:"); scanf_s("%d", &list[i]->age);
        printf("salary:"); scanf_s("%f", &list[i]->salary);
        head++;
    }

    for (int i = head; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printf("%d name :%s, age: %dage, salary:%fsalary", i, list[i]->name, list[i]->age, list[i]->salary);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: About the last for-loop, i must be decrementing (i--)

Comment: Ahhh yes hahahaha I forgot hahahaha thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Stack actually works by putting the reference of the data block or group of the data blocks to the last data that was added to it. In this case since you are using arrays as data block to store values, the reference were dependent to its index.

Adding stacks

```
|2| <- added value
|1|
```

Add 4 as new value to this stack and you'll get

```
|4|<- added value
|2|
|1|
```

And pop a value to the stack and you'll have the stack looking like this

```
|2|
|1|
```

Therefore stack is all about manipulating the latest values you added to the array/list down to the oldest  value you added to the array/list. I think a good way of approaching this problem is to initialize a head (integer) variable that will store the index of the last element added to the array and loop from that head reference to 0.